# Can Keras.load_img work on multiple images in folder

Tags: python, keras

I'm working on an algorithm to classify pictures of dogs and cats using Keras. As per the code below, this works when I feed in one image, but my question is can Keras.load_img work on multiple images in a folder? When I try this it says list object has no attributes seek and read.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
prediction = 'dog'
else:
prediction = 'cat'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a solution, you can try this:

```
images = []
for img in os.listdir(folder_path):
    img = image.load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
    img = img.img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    images.append(img)
images = np.vstack(images)
classes = classifier.predict(images, batch_size=10)
print(classes)
```

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer to help other users understand how it works, and why! :)

Comment: This works for putting the output in an array, but what I'm looking for is to pass an array to image.load_img, e.g. img = image.load_img(images,  target_size=(img_width, img_height))

Comment: Suboptimal solution, using `for` loops should not be accepted.